# Using Extjs Ajax proxy with rails rest server

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to call via GET method, my server action /users/menus, but it seams to work only with REST proxy.

Here is my store declaration:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Menu', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',   
model: 'App.model.Menu',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'        
    },
    api: {
        read: 'users/menus'
    }
}
});
```

and here is how I load the store:

```
var store = Ext.create('App.store.Menu').load({
    id: 1,
    callback: function () {
        //do something...
    }
});
```

and this is my rails code:

```
def menus
  @user = User.find(params[:id])  
  @menus = @user.menus
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # menus.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @menus }
  end
end
```

I get this error on the server:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=menus):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in `show'
```

But if I use REST proxy, I get correct request:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Menu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',   
    model: 'App.model.Menu',
    proxy: {
      type: 'rest',
      format: 'json',
      url: 'users/menus'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your url schema is a REST schema and then you should use a rest proxy. This is how both proxies send the Id value:

**Ajax proxy**: yourdomain.com/users/menus?id=1

**Rest proxy**: yourdomain.com/users/menus/1

There is no reason to use and ajax proxy when your application understand a rest schema. However, if you want to force things in order to be able to use an ajax request, you can modify your proxy as follow:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Menu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',   
    model: 'App.model.Menu',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'users/menus',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'        
        },
        buildUrl: function(request) {
            debugger;
            var me = this,
                url = me.getUrl(request),
                operation = request.operation,
                id  = operation.id;

            if (id) {
                if (!url.match(/\/$/)) {
                    url += '/';
                }

                url += id;
            }  
            return url;            
        }
    }    
});
```

This does something similar that rest proxy but it is an ajax proxy.

Good luck!